# Error installing ibm_db: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, rubygems, db2

Ok, so I'm trying to install de ibm_db gem this time and this is the error i get:

root@ubuntu:~# sudo gem install ibm_db
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ibm_db:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

Detected 32-bit Ruby

Environment variable IBM_DB_HOME is not set. Set it to your DB2/IBM_Data_Server_Driver installation directory and retry gem install.

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ibm_db-2.5.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ibm_db-2.5.11/ext/gem_make.out

Im really lost, i dunno what to do!! Help… please?

Comment: I had to change the version to 2.5.10 so there's no gem_make.out… how can i create it? I change the version in config/database.yml so I'm not quite sure how to create it.

Comment: It was a problem while executing install ibm_db cuz it was installing using -v '2.5.11' and i needed -v '2.5.10' thnx! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, but in order to install the DB2 drivers for a programming language you need at least have installed a DB2 client on the same machine. A DB2 client could be the "IBM Data Server Client" that will have the headers (.h) and all libraries needed to build your driver. This client is free of charge, just google to find where can you get it.

Comment: yeah thnx! i solve the problem since i already had the db2 but a different version… thnk you! :D